# syncing finished but stuck returning zeros

Tags: go-ethereum

in the process of deploying a smart contract I've run into problems on both Ropsten and Mainnet.

I've run

```
geth --rpc --rpcapi eth,net,web3,personal --rpcport 8545 --testnet
```

in one terminal window until the blockchain is finished syncing.

```
$ geth --testnet attach     
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.8.1-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.10
coinbase: 0xc4f4d7ef579df808b8bd201345bbe30efa8a59c5
at block: 0 (Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 EST)
 datadir: /Users/asdf/Library/Ethereum/testnet
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 2737469,
  highestBlock: 2737534,
  knownStates: 16511,
  pulledStates: 14936,
  startingBlock: 2737424
}
> eth.syncing
false
> eth.blockNumber
0
```

everything else I check comes back with zeros.  getBalance for any account I can find also returns 0.

I have replicated this on OSX and Linux.

Comment: If `eth.blockNumber` is returning 0 then it didn't finish syncing. It appears that geth v1.8 will set eth.syncing to false before it has finished.

Answer (score 1):

`eth.syncing` returns false when the blocks have been downloaded, but it doesn't reflect the States that have to be downloaded as well.  Apparently a common cause of confusion.

Let `geth` continue to run and download all state updates.